# using feature selection to improve model performance

Tags: python, regression, feature-selection, random-forest

I have a highly sparse dataset that I am using to predict a continuous variable via a random forest regression. I have achieved an acceptable level of performance following cross-validation, and I am now thinking of potential ways I might further improve accuracy.

Given that my dataset is highly sparse, I was thinking that recursive feature elimination (using the cross validated version in sklearn) might be a good way to go. My understanding is that this will give me the 'optimal' number of features and thus may reduce issues related to over-fitting.

My question is, is it then appropriate to re-run the analysis with these optimized features, or am I in someway biasing the model? I have a test set that has not been used at all in training/validation, so I am assuming that as long as I don't leak info between training and testing, I should be good. But I'm unclear if these assumptions are correct.

Is this a suitable use of RFE, or should i be considering a different path?

For info, my training/validation dataset is 370 rows, with approx. 900 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

370 rows, with approx. 900 features is not optimal. I would suggest some dimension reduction. PCA, factor analysis, PLS regression are some alternatives.

You could try a lasso- / elasticnet -regression as well.

Here is a good guide. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html